# style transitions don't seem to work when called from a setInterval function (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

```
function updateGrid() {
//this for loop moves the matrix and sets a position 
    for (var row = row_start; row < row_end; row+=5) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //these for loops call each individual rect on the grid by a unique id.
            d3.select("#x-"+row+"y-"+(i*20))
                .transition()
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    var alt = 0;
                    switch (i) {
                        //ignore this switch statement. It's just reversing the i because the tag is backwards.
                        case 0: alt = 4; break;
                        case 1: alt = 3; break;
                        case 3: alt = 1; break;
                        case 4: alt = 0; break;
                        default: alt = 2; break;
                    }
                    //color_matrix is an object. row is the key, and alt is the position of the array that is the key value.
                    if (color_matrix[row][alt] == 0) return colors[0]; 
                    if (color_matrix[row][alt] == 1) return colors[1]; 
                    if (color_matrix[row][alt] == 2) return colors[2]; 
                    if (color_matrix[row][alt] == 3) return colors[3]; 
                    if (color_matrix[row][alt] >= 4) return colors[4]; 
                })
                .duration(750);
        }
    }
    //this moves the matrix by one column. console.log() shows that it works.
    row_start += 5;
    row_end += 5;
}

var run = window.setInterval(function() { updateGrid() }, 5000);
```

So I cannot seem to figure this one out. A few things to note first:
1. The colors work perfectly in the rect initialization.
2. The transition works correctly the first time as well.
3. The function is being called correctly, because I console.log() tested it.
4. The matrix/object is also cycling correctly.
5. the position of duration doesn't seem to matter.

The only thing that doesn't work correctly is the color change. This update function will be called every five seconds to change the color of the rects. However, it doesn't seem to work. Is there something wrong with the way the transition is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the matrix wasn't cycling correctly after all. The for loop was trying to cycle rect where there wasn't any, and to fix it I added a separate increment.